# Set a variable to the range that is contained within a hyperlink

Tags: excel

VBA Question - but I am trying to define hRange as a range that is contained within another cell. I have cell A9 which contains a hyperlink to a range within the same sheet.

So as an example, A9 has a visible value of "Section 5" and the hyperlink is essentially "file://C:\Folder\Workbookname.xlsm - 'SheetName'!R195C1:R1075C10"

Long story short - I want hRange to be R195C1:R1075C10. My true goal would be achieved if I could set hRangeStart as R195 and hRangeEnd as R1075, but I can probably handle this once I figure out how to extract the address from the hyperlink.

I've tried a few different things with Hyperlink.Address and Hyperlink.SubAddress - but no luck getting the variable to stick

Comment: What specifically have you tried? `Subaddress` should work I think, though you'd have to convert the range to a string.

Comment: I tried a few different things. It didn't entirely click that the SubAddress was a string, so I was having trouble trying to set my range to that since I could set a Range to a String value. I'm also not sure if R1C1 is common/expected for the SubAddress, but I'm guessing it might be. To make it all a bit more robust though, I ended up creating a function to return the range after parsing the data from the string based on assumptions with the file/link naming conventions. Should be able to use the function to return the rest of the objects as well if needed, but I truly only need the range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I landed after some trial and error. I know if works for my situation, although I'm guessing there are some improvements that could be made to make it either cleaner or faster. Such is the way with coding.

```
Function hlinkRange(rng As Range) As Range
'Function to extract a range from a hyperlink
'Basically, pass in the cell with the hyperlink, this function should perform the following actions:
'First - get the SubAddress of the hyperlink which is a string reference to the WB.Sheet.Range in R1C1
'Second - convert the string reference from R1C1 to A1 reference style so it can be Set as a range
'Third - we need to parse the string reference into 3 parts: Workbook, Sheet, Range
'Finally - Set the new range to the extracted and newly parsed reference in A1 style

Dim SubAddressR1C1 As String
Dim SubAddressA1 As String
Dim WBstr As String
Dim WSstr As String
Dim Rangestr As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

If rng(1).Hyperlinks.Count Then SubAddressR1C1 = rng.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress Else Exit Function 'Get the SubAddress as a string in R1C1
SubAddressA1 = Application.ConvertFormula(SubAddressR1C1, xlR1C1, xlA1) 'Convert the SubAddress to xlA1
WBstr = Mid(SubAddressA1, InStr(1, SubAddressA1, "[") + 1, InStrRev(SubAddressA1, "]") - InStr(1, SubAddressA1, "[") - 1) 'Parse the WB name
WSstr = Mid(SubAddressA1, (Len(WBstr) + 3) + 1, InStrRev(SubAddressA1, "'") - (Len(WBstr) + 3) - 1) 'Parse the WS name
Rangestr = Mid(SubAddressA1, (Len(WBstr) + 3) + (Len(WSstr) + 2) + 1) 'Parse the Range

Set WB = Workbooks(WBstr)
Set WS = Sheets(WSstr)
Set hlinkRange = Range(Rangestr)

End Function
```

After much ado, I realize now that all of that parsing is fun and good practice for extracting substrings from a string - but getting the range is a lot easier.

```
Function hlinkRange(rng As Range) As Range
'Function to extract a range from a hyperlink

Dim SubAddressR1C1 As String
Dim SubAddressA1 As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

If rng(1).Hyperlinks.Count Then SubAddressR1C1 = rng.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress Else Exit Function 'Get the SubAddress as a string in R1C1
SubAddressA1 = Application.ConvertFormula(SubAddressR1C1, xlR1C1, xlA1) 'Convert the SubAddress to xlA1

Set hlinkRange = Range(SubAddressA1)
Set WS = hlinkRange.Parent
Set WB = hlinkRange.Parent.Parent

End Function
```